# What components reflect on changes in backgroundColor property of ThemeData in Flutter?

Tags: flutter, themes

I begin study properties of ThemeData class (https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/ThemeData-class.html)

And get stuck with property - backgroundColor. I could not find an information where it is used. I tested in Android Studio several widgets:

- only text,
- Scaffold
- ChoiceChip (by default backgroundColor is  light    grey)
- LinearProgressIndicator or progress bar (reflects)

I looked through https://material.io/design/color/applying-color-to-ui.html as well.

It is not mentioned what components (widgets) reflect on changes in backgroundColor property of ThemeData in Flutter? Except LinearProgressIndicator

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() => runApp(MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      theme: ThemeData(
        accentIconTheme: IconThemeData(color:Colors.deepOrange),
        backgroundColor: Colors.red,
        primaryColor: Colors.teal,
      ),
      home: HomePage(),
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

On the page you've posted: https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/ThemeData-class.html

It does say what backgroundColor does, just scroll down some or search for it:

> backgroundColor → Color.
>
> A color that contrasts with the primaryColor, e.g. used as the
>   remaining part of a progress bar.

Or in a separate link:
https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/ThemeData/backgroundColor.html

Not very intuitive IMHO, but at least they did document it.

That being said I think you will find these two more useful for your application:

> dialogBackgroundColor → Color
>
> The background color of Dialog elements.

-

> scaffoldBackgroundColor → Color
>
> The default color of the Material that
>   underlies the Scaffold. The background color for a typical material
>   app or a page within the app.